# Request.Url.Host vs Request.Url.Authority

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've inherited an ASP.NET web application written in C#. In many pages throughout the site the hostname is retrieved using:

```
BaseHost = Request.Url.Host;
```

Since I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express and it's installed local IIS Express server, I seem to be stuck with a port number appended to the hostname (localhost) when I debug/run locally. The above code does not result in the port number being included and as such breaks links that are generated by code (menu item links, redirects, etc).

I see that I can overcome the issue by changing the code to:

```
BaseHost = Request.Url.Authority;
```

This seems to fix it by including the port when I'm running locally (localhost:4652) and when published to my staging server (development.mysite.com).

My question: Is this bad form? Is there a time or a situation in which this is going to cause problems on my live site? It just seems a lot easier to do a quick replace of all these instances. I've considered writing a small routine to append `: with Request.Url.Port`, but it seems easier just to use `Request.Url.Authority`. Too easy maybe...

I've tried to research my question online and at MSDN, but I don't see an answer.

Comment: You can check if you are on a localhost and apply one or the other: if (Request.Url.Host == "localhost") {....}

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx) `Authority` includes the port number while `Host` does not. Another aspect is that `Authority` will escape reserved characters if need be.

Without knowing your application it is hard to say whether it is a good idea, but in general I would suspect that it won't break anything... so go ahead...

Another option is to run the application IIS instead of IIS Express...

Comment: One small doubt. if I run the application in localhost I have port number in my URL but in production I do not have port number in the URL. So, I can freely use Url.Authority right? I mean if port number is not there then URl.Authority will act same as URL.Host right. I mean I will still be able to get the URL correctly right? please guide me,.

Answer (score 2):

My problem with this is that it ALWAYS adds the port, even when the port is not required. This can cause issues with multiple servers in some cases For example, in a production server environment behind a firewall on a pair of load-balanced web servers, it kept putting the firewall port in place, but that caused the URL to break because the port was tied to a specific web server in the server farm that wouldn't map correctly through the firewall. So I would be very careful with this method if you're using it across multiple servers. It caused a breaking issue with our application and had to be reverted back to using Url.Host. Plus, it made production web URL's look weird with the port number.

Comment: I'm only seeing the Authority contain the port if the URL has the port. So I think it does not ALWAYS add the port.

Comment: It definitely does always add it in a server farm situation (load-balanced web servers) even if the port isn't part of the URL in the browser. So perhaps that's more of a point of caution as I said for using it with multiple servers behind a load balancer.

Comment: One small doubt. if I run the application in localhost I have port number in my URL but in production I do not have port number in the URL. So, I can freely use Url.Authority right? I mean if port number is not there then URl.Authority will act same as URL.Host right. I mean I will still be able to get the URL correctly right? please guide me,.

Comment: You should be good, yep. It's only a concern in a server-farm environment where the firewall is re-writing the URL in passing to preserve the server choice (for making sticky sessions).